# App crashes after ok button click on alert dialog on android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

please help me with this as I have searched for solutions online without getting one.

What I am trying to do is get data from an alert dialog onclick the OK button.
The alert dialog pops up after clicking an item on TypeActivity. The result of this click is passed to HomeActivity from where the alert dialog pops up with a text field.
But each time I type in the text field and press the "OK" button, the app crashes.
The logcat shows A null pointer Exception. I will display the logcat content too. Thanks for your help.

My codes are as follows

TypeActivity:

```
    String[] typeTag = {"TypeA","TypeB","TypeC","TypeD"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(TypeActivity.this,R.layout.spinnerrow, typeTag));
    getListView().setAdapter(new MyAdapter(TypeActivity.this,R.layout.spinnerrow, typeTag));


    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("selectedType", typeTag[position]);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

HomeActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String temp = data.getStringExtra("selectedType");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this); 
            LayoutInflater inflater = HomeActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup parent = null;
            builder2.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtype, parent, false));

            final EditText tagname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);                        

            builder2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {                   

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String tag = tagname.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U entered "+tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
            })
            .show();  
        }
    }
```

The Logcat:

```
1-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2298
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.example.myapp.HomeActivity$3.onClick(HomeActivity.java:278)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-11 05:22:45.427: E/AndroidRuntime(2298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the new logcat

```
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 4530
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530): java.lang.NullPointerException
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at com.example.myapp.HomeActivity$3.onClick(HomeActivity.java:282)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 11-11 06:06:35.917: E/AndroidRuntime(4530):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/dispimg"        
   android:layout_width="match_parent"        
   android:layout_height="64dp"        
   android:background="#d1d1d1"        
   android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"        
   android:scaleType="center"        
   android:src="@drawable/addme" /> 

    <EditText        
     android:id="@+id/uname"        
     android:layout_width="match_parent"        
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"        
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"        
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"        
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"                
     android:inputType="text"
     android:background="@drawable/textfield" />   

     </LinearLayout>
```

the new code:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String temp = data.getStringExtra("selectedType");            

            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);              
            LayoutInflater inflater = HomeActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup parent = null;
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtype, parent, true);
             final EditText tagname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);   
             builder2.setView(view);

            builder2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {                   

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String tag = tagname.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U entered "+tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                 .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                 })
                .show();  
            }
        }
```

new logcat:

```
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 7148
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.example.myapp.HomeActivity$3.onClick(HomeActivity.java:288)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    11-11 06:58:49.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is `line 278 of HomeActivity?`

Comment: String tag = tagname.getText().toString();

Comment: shayan is right. upvote!

Comment: I have tried it and not yet working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your editText is belong to AlertDialog, so following line is null in your code:

```
 final EditText tagname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
```

so you get NPE on

```
String tag = tagname.getText().toString();
```

you need following code:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtype, parent, false)
 builder2.setView(view);
```

and

```
 final EditText tagname = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.uname);
```

so your code must be as following:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this); 
            LayoutInflater inflater = HomeActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup parent = null;
             View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtype, parent, false);
             final EditText tagname = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.uname); 
             builder2.setView(view);




            builder2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {                   

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String tag = tagname.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U entered "+tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
            })
            .show();
```

Comment: I have tried it,i'm still getting the NPE. But is this builder2.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputacct, parent, false)); not equivalent to View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtype, parent, false)
 builder2.setView(view);

Comment: move this line: `final EditText tagname = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.uname); ` before `setView`.

Comment: thanks for your effort shayan pourvatan.I have tried your modified code, i'm still getting the NPE and a crash

Comment: try move editText initialize line before setView, i edited my post, use that

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki and shayan pourvatan: thanks, i have tried your suggestions, the NPE persists followed by the crash

Comment: make sure you have `uname` id in `inputtype` layout

Comment: Yes,that's where it is

Comment: post new logcat and new code, and post layout file too

Comment: I have edited my question with the new information  shayan pourvatan

Comment: you have forgotten view before findvViewById(), see my answer one more time you need view.findViewById()

Comment: you have forgotten view before findvViewById(), see my answer one more time you need view.findViewById()

Comment: @shayan pourvatan: you are wonderful! It works. I appreciate your help.Thanks